# IIS SERVER curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file

Tags: php, curl

I spent a lot of time search about this issue but unfortunately I didn't found nothing to solve this.

I have a server iis on EC2 Windows 2008 R2 and trying to create a user through intercom API.

> curl_setopt_array(): Unable to create temporary file.

I have already give permission to iusr on tmp folder and I can do uploads with no problems to the server.

The PHP seems to can't do writes on any folders because the log archive is still empty.

I don't know if it is useless or not but I can't use not sessions either cookies on PHP

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the `sys_temp_dir` php.ini Part and not the `upload_tmp_dir` setting.

Comment: at least for me it was the sys_temp_dir

Answer (score 1):

Open php.ini and find for `upload_tmp_dir` 
The value looks like *"C:\windows\Temp\"*
Now Open Temp folder properties and give all permissions to *IIS_IUSRS* and *Administrators*
Click Apply. I've solved this problem by following these steps.